# Not able to read value from <a> tag

Tags: javascript

I have created a simple html and javascript page where there are two a tags.
Upon pressing the READ ME button, the first a tag gets populated with a random number

Upon pressing the POPULATE button, I am trying to read to the value of the first a tag and populate the second a tag with the value

But its not working. The second a tag is getting populated with a UNDEFINED value.

Why is that?

```
<html>
<body>
   <p>
        <a id="first"></a><br>
        <a id="second"></a><br>
        <button id="readme" onclick="readme()">Read Me</button><br>
        <button ="populate" onclick="populate()">Populate</button>
   </p>

</body>
<script>

function readme()
{
    document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
}

function populate()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `a` tag does not have a `value` property.

Comment: You need `var x = document.getElementById("first").innerHTML;`

Comment: In addition to Rajesh's comment see here available attributes for  ```a``` tag: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: @OlivierKrull That is the worst reference available. Refer to mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a or really anything else.

Comment: @AluanHaddad really? so could you provide a better one? maybe mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a?

Comment: @AluanHaddad oh sorry didn't see that you already postet the link

Comment: Not a problem. I'll delete my first comment if you delete yours :p

Comment: Thanks guys. This worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use innerHTML:

```
function populate(){
   var x = document.getElementById("first").innerHTML;
   document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = x;

   // you can also directly set values instead of using temp variable
   document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = document.getElementById("first").innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Consider fixing the code style by using standard JavaScript brace placement.